# Cancelling OnFormClosing and task manager

Tags: c#, winforms, taskmanager

According to MSDN 
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onformclosing.aspx

I am trying to block a user from closing a form (except for windows shutting down).

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason != CloseReason.WindowsShutDown)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        wiggle();
    }
    base.OnFormClosing(e);
}
```

When closing from the task manager "End task" button, the window do not closes as expected but I get an error after a few seconds

[image]

How does windows determines if a program is responding or not ! 
All the form does is nothing...

Comment: What does `wiggle()` do?

Comment: Delete wiggle() from this code.

Comment: @Hans: will you please share the reason for your advice?

Comment: @Charles - it will work without it.

Comment: @Hans, that's not at all helpful. With all your knowledge, it's a real shame about your attitude.

Comment: @Charles - of course it is.  The OP is not responding, he's fixing his wiggle function.  Attitude has little to do with it, it isn't a substitute for invisible code.

Comment: @Hans: it would be helpful to not just the OP but everyone else, if you would explain why the wiggle call is causing the problem. Knowing the cure is good but understanding the cause is better. Are you averse to giving more than the absolute minimum amount of help possible?

Comment: @Charles - what are you going about?  Do you think that wiggle() is a standard .NET function?  It is not.

Comment: @Hans: of course I don't. But you seem to be sure that removing it will fix the problem - I just want to know why. Are you assuming some code in wiggle() is hanging the program?

Comment: @UweKeim The wiggle() was just a function that moves the position of the window. Even after deleting it, I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Task Manager asked the program to close and it didn't.  At least in WinXP, the Task Manager doesn't like that and pops up the "Not Responding" window after several seconds.

It is typically a bad design to try and prevent app closings, especially this way.  The next tab on TaskMan will bypass any such checks.